# Как получить View из ListView

Tags: android

`ListView` заполняется `View`, которые выдает адаптер ("засовывая" их в контейнер"). Как получить эти `View` (массивом или по отдельности без разницы)?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что гладиолус, ну а если серьезно, то такое ощущение что данный пользователь при малейшей же проблеме и не понятной ситуации задает вопрос, при чем периодами с очень большой частотой. В следствии чего хотелось бы предложить данному пользователю попробовать самостоятельно разобраться с некоторыми моментами, SO конечно всегда поможет, но...да и  почаще пользоваться поисковиком.

Comment: @ermak0ff Ну .. контент генерирует :) хотя немного самостоятельности и воли к победе, действительно, не помешало бы.

Comment: @pavlofff контент конечно хорошо) но он должен быть интересным ну или разнообразным что ли, а тут получается мы уже какой день возимся с ListView и его адаптером)

Comment: @ermak0ff, а вот и разнообразие! `onTouch` в адаптере `ListView`! :D — http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464957/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-action-down-%D0%B2-ontouch-%D0%B2-listview Надеюсь, что это последний вопрос, про адаптер...

Comment: @pavlofff жизнь - боль)))

Comment: @ermak0ff Не нравится отвечать — не отвечайте, тут желающих отвечать достаточно, не надо им мешать. Вон, по WPF тоже "генератор контента" есть, я только рад.

Comment: @Discord да так я Вам как то помешал уважаемый, отвечайте кто запрещает, я лишь попытался в человеке зародить хоть чуточку самостоятельности, но по всей видимости безрезультатно...

Comment: @ermak0ff Закладывать самостоятельность нужно вдохновляющими комментариями и разумными рекомендациями, а не закрытием вопросов по надуманным причинам.

Comment: @ну так изначально Ваш вариант и использовали, результат как видим на лицо, Вы просто по всей видимости мониторите данную ветку не часто

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить `View` из произвольной позиции, требуется проделать не очень хитрую манипуляцию. Напишем метод, который по значению позиции и экземпляру списка вернет `View` для этой позиции:

```
 public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

Такие "сложности" связаны с тем, что "готовых" `View` есть только те, что видимы в данный момент на экране, чтобы получить невидимые - их нужно предварительно создать.

Если вам достаточно только видимых `View`, то все гораздо проще. Строка:

`listView.getChildAt(positionOnScreen);`

вернет вам их, с таким расчетом, что *positionOnScreen = 0* - это первая видимая на экране позиция (а не реальная позиция в списке)

[enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24864536)

Comment: Все понятно, но хочу уточнить, `getChildCount` возвращает количество видимых позиций? И почему -1?

Comment: Да, видимых.  -1 потому, что счетчик содержит количество элементов, в то время, как отсчет позиций начинается с нуля. То есть, для 10-ти элементов позиции будут 0-9

Answer (score 2):

У `ListView` есть метод [getChildAt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)), который возвращает View с определённым индексом. Чтобы получить все View, нужно в цикле вызывать этот метод:

```
for(int viewID = 0; viewID < listView.getChildCount(); viewID++)
{
    View view = listView.getChildAt(viewID);
}
```

Comment: Не все `View`, а только видимые в данный момент на экране. Невидимые еще не созданы и не могут быть возвращены этим методом