# Некорректная работа ACTION_DOWN в onTouch в ListView

Tags: android

У меня есть `ListView` и его адаптер, в который поступает массив данных (если честно два, но возьмем только один). Каждый контейнер (`View`), который возвращает адаптер, содержит три текстовых поля и один `LinearLayout`. Для `LinearLayout'a` я назначаю слушатель `onTouch`. Слушатель правильно работает, но, если нажать на `View` (элемент в `ListView`) и передвинуть — при смещении сразу же срабатывает `ACTION_CANCEL`!

**Вопрос:** как сделать так, чтобы, после того, как `View` передвинут, корректно сработал вызов `ACTION_UP`?

---

Вот сам адаптер (назначение слушателей в `getView`):

```
public class CustomListAdapter_Words extends BaseAdapter {

        private final String TAG = "myApplication";
        private final String MSG = "Adapter: ";

        private final int FIRST_WORDS = 0;
        private final int SECOND_WORDS = 1;
        private final int FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH;

        private final Activity mContext;
        private final String[][] mWordsForm1;
        private final String[][] mWordsForm2;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public CustomListAdapter_Words(Activity context, String[][] wordsForm1, String[][] wordsForm2) {

            mContext = context;
            mWordsForm1 = wordsForm1;
            mWordsForm2 = wordsForm2;
            mInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH = mWordsForm1.length;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                switch (type) {
                    case FIRST_WORDS:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_1, null, true);

                        holder.textView1Form1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
                        holder.textView2Form1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
                        holder.textView3Form1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_3);

                        holder.linearLayout_1 = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_1);
                        break;
                    case SECOND_WORDS:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_2, null, true);

                        holder.textView1Form2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
                        holder.textView2Form2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
                        holder.textView3Form2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_3);
                        holder.textView4Form2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_4);
                        holder.textView5Form2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_5);

                        holder.linearLayout_2 = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_2);
                        break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            switch (type) {
                case FIRST_WORDS:
                    holder.textView1Form1.setText(mWordsForm1[position][0]);
                    holder.textView2Form1.setText(mWordsForm1[position][1]);
                    holder.textView3Form1.setText(mWordsForm1[position][2]);


                    holder.linearLayout_1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            switch (event.getAction()) {
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                    holder.textView1Form1.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    holder.textView2Form1.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    holder.textView3Form1.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

                                    return true;
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                    Log.i(TAG, MSG + "ACTION UP");
                                    holder.textView1Form1.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                                    holder.textView2Form1.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                                    holder.textView3Form1.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

                                    return true;
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                                    Log.i(TAG, MSG + "ACTION CANCEL");
                                    return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    break;

                case SECOND_WORDS:
                    holder.textView1Form2.setText(mWordsForm2[position - FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH][0]);
                    holder.textView2Form2.setText(mWordsForm2[position - FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH][1]);
                    holder.textView3Form2.setText(mWordsForm2[position - FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH][2]);
                    holder.textView4Form2.setText(mWordsForm2[position - FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH][3]);
                    holder.textView5Form2.setText(mWordsForm2[position - FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH][4]);
                    holder.linearLayout_2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                            switch (event.getAction()) {
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                    holder.textView1Form2.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    holder.textView2Form2.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    holder.textView3Form2.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    holder.textView4Form2.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    holder.textView5Form2.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

                                    return true;
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                    holder.textView1Form2.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                                    holder.textView2Form2.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                                    holder.textView3Form2.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                                    holder.textView4Form2.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                                    holder.textView5Form2.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

                                    return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return (mWordsForm1.length + mWordsForm2.length);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return (position < mWordsForm1.length) ? FIRST_WORDS : SECOND_WORDS;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            String[][] item = new String[1][8];

            item[0][0] = mWordsForm1[position][0];
            item[0][1] = mWordsForm1[position][1];
            item[0][2] = mWordsForm1[position][2];

            item[0][3] = mWordsForm2[position][0];
            item[0][4] = mWordsForm2[position][1];
            item[0][5] = mWordsForm2[position][2];
            item[0][6] = mWordsForm2[position][3];
            item[0][7] = mWordsForm2[position][4];
            return item;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            public TextView textView1Form1;
            public TextView textView2Form1;
            public TextView textView3Form1;
            public TextView textView1Form2;
            public TextView textView2Form2;
            public TextView textView3Form2;
            public TextView textView4Form2;
            public TextView textView5Form2;
            public LinearLayout linearLayout_1;
            public LinearLayout linearLayout_2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Меня упорно преследует подозрение, что вы пытаетесь сделать что-то очень простое очень сложным путём. Расскажите сразу, что должно быть в итоге?

Comment: @saturov, ну... Мне нужно засунуть в `ListView` два массива, чтобы они выглядели как таблица, но, при этом, каждый пункт нужно выделять (для удаления\изменения). Из-за того, что у меня стоит белый фон (`android:background="@color/white"`), средства `ListView` не хотят выделять элемент. P.S. Потом я буду пытаться редактировать\удалять отдельные `View` не перезапуская весь список.

Comment: Поскольку вопросов с этим несчастным списком уже наверное больше десятка, я уже давно подозреваю, что здесь классическая Проблема X Y и автор вместо того, чтобы озвучить действительную проблему, пытается решить ее через другое место, какими то невероятными и неправильными способами, задавая вопросы по ним, а не по реальной проблеме.

Comment: Так для реализации выделения достаточно в качестве бэкграунда прописать свой селектор, а не задавать статический фон.

Comment: @pavlofff, вы сговорились что ли?) Не выходит у меня прописать `selector`! Мне нужно ловить выделение `LinearLayout`, а цвет менять — трем `TextView`. Если так и можно сделать, я не нашел внятного объяснения как.

Comment: @bukashka101 насколько я помню, TextView реализует интерфейс Checkable, т.е. ему можно сделать setCheked(true). но в данном случае, вам надо просто прописать android:duplicateParentState="true" у всех этих TextView в XML, далее, используя этот CheckableLinearLayout (https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/samples/CustomChoiceList/src/com.example.android.customchoicelist/CheckableLinearLayout.html) выделять его. И все вьюхи будут также выделяться.

Comment: @saturov, тогда в `background` прописать состояние для выделенного состояния и в нем менять цвет? Но тогда вопрос: а как менять состояние `LinearLayout` на `check = true` только на время его удержания? Стоп! А можно как-то в `selector` прописать для `LinearLayout`, что, если `LinearLayout` в состоянии нажатия, то состояние выделение становится `true`?

Comment: @bukashka101 вас будет интересовать состояния selected. оно будет true только пока вы держите палец

Comment: @saturov, а... ну да. Я немного усложняю себе жизнь :). Хотел для в `pressed` менять `selected`... А, если не секрет, как сделать `LinearLayout` `CheckableLinearLayout'ом`?

Comment: @bukashka101 вот там вот код, по ссылочке, в моём сообщении выше. копируйте его как отдельный класс в своё приложение. Далее, кладёте на XML не LinearLayout, а CheckableLinearLayout. Ну и всё по сути.

Comment: @saturov, Вы гений! :D В ответ закиньте.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31302/discussion-between-saturov-and-bukashka101).

Comment: Теперь у нас другая проблема - принятый ответ никак не соответствует вопросу. Пожалуйста, переоформите вопрос так, чтобы принятый вами ответ был по существу вопроса. Что то вроде "Как сделать селектор для реакции на вложенные в Layout элементы" и описание проблемы, которая в топе этого ресурса уже несколько дней :)

Comment: @pavlofff, я лучше ответ подкорректирую :)) (он, кстати, немного изменился).

Comment: @pavlofff, извменил ответ, так что теперь все хорошо (осталось дождаться подтверждения правки).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вы хотите сделать реализуется через `CheckableLinearLayout`. `TextView` реализует интерфейс `Checkable`, т.е. ему можно сделать `setCheked(true)`. Hо в данном случае, вам надо просто прописать `android:duplicateParentState="true"` у всех этих `TextView` в XML, далее, используя `CheckableLinearLayout` выделять его. И все `View` будут также выделяться.

---

1. Вы должны скопировать этот класс к себе — [тык](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/samples/CustomChoiceList/src/com.example.android.customchoicelist/CheckableLinearLayout.html). В .xml разметке
   использовать вместо `LinearLayout` `CheckableLinearLayout`.
2. В `TextView` (которые находятся) прописать: `android:duplicateParentState="true"`
3. А в `background` назначить `drawable` файл с `selector`, в котором задан цвет `android:background="@color/цвет"` для `android:state_checked="true"`.

Comment: Тут `CheckableLinearLayout`глючит — http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465009/layoutinflater-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-checkedlinearlayout

Comment: @bukashka101 Наверное это потому, что `TextView` все же не реализует `Checkable`/ Его реализует [`CheckedTextView`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html)

Comment: @pavlofff ну да, вы правы. только не уверен, что у той ошибки ноги отсюда растут.

Comment: @pavlofff, наверное Вы правы... Попробую изменить `TextView` на `CheckedTextView`. А остальной код будет понимать `CheckedTextView`, как `TextView` или это уже выбьет несовпадение типов?

Comment: @pavlofff, возможно Вы правы. Нашел класс `CheckedTextView`, но он тоже не хочет инфлейтироваться... — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465119/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-c-infalter%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-checkedtextview

Answer (score 0):

Судя по комментариям тебе нужен просто ActionMode...

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/183-urok-113-android-3-actionmode-kak-alternativa-kontekstnomu-menju

http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/view/ActionMode.html

Comment: Это совсем другое... И у меня вообще экшн бара нет :).

Answer (score 0):

Я понял в чем проблема! Слушатель накладывался на `LinearLayout`, то есть, на пункт в `ListView`. Во время пролистывания палец выходит за пределы слушателя. Тогда слушатель не понимает, куда пропал... палец и выдает ошибку (а точнее, экстренный выход) — `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL`.

Comment: Проблема более глобальная. Вы уж извините, но всё что вышел было сказано, это правда. Вы пишете сомнительный код, задаёте по нему вопросы, которые только сильнее вводят вас в заблуждение, вместо того, чтобы изучить основы или хотя бы просто спросить "а как сделать это правильно?". Не надо делать по наитию "лишь бы работало". Это ужасная практика. В андроиде очень много паттернов, которым надо следовать. Интернет даёт возможность их все изучить. Написано куча книг и постов. Изучайте их и всё у вас получится.

Comment: @saturov, знаю :(. Сейчас это приложение допишу и пойду читать книгу по андроиду.

Comment: Книг надо будет прочитать гораздо больше, чем одну :)