# LayoutInflater не понимает CheckedLinearLayout

Tags: android

У меня есть класс `CheckableLinearLayout`:

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {android.R.attr.state_checked};

    private boolean mChecked = false;

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean b) {
        if (b != mChecked) {
            mChecked = b;
            refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }
```

Я его использую в `layout'e` вместо `LinearLayout`. При попытке заинфлейтировать этот `layout` через `View convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_1, null, true);`, выскакивает ошибка:

Вот stacktrace:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.CustomListAdapter_Words.getView(CustomListAdapter_Words.java:46)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1627)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1652)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExce
```

.xml разметка:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.CheckableLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="46"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_3"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="46"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />
</com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Укажите в разметке полное имя класса, включая имя пакета

```
<my.package.subpackage.CheckableLinearLayout ...
```

Comment: Попробовал. Ошибка осталась. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @bukashka101, Ошибка уже другая. Отметьте этот ответ, как правильный, и задайте новый вопрос, т. к. он решил вашу проблему, но у вас появилась новая

Comment: Ошибка другая теперь, похоже на ошибку в разметке.

Comment: @metalurgus, но мою проблему он не решил! Разве ответ не стает им, пока все проблемы не исчезнут (я хорошо помню, как ЮрийСПб, pavlofff, saturov и другие исправляли со мной ошибки до тех пор, пока все не заработает)!